# Android if value not working

Tags: android

I am having problem,

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String res = getServerData("http://10.0.2.2/auth.php?username="+username.getText()+"&password="+password.getText());
        //txt.setText(res);
        if("true".equals(res))
            txt.setText("SUCESS");
        else
            txt.setText("FAILED");
    }
});
```

Why this conditions keep on FAILED even though if i uncomment txt.setText(res) it display as true. any idea why?

Thank you..

Comment: My best suggestion will be to go into debug mode and check whether it goes through the if and the exact content of res. It seems to me that it doesn't go through the if, otherwise the textview should have been displaying SUCCESS given that it's properly initialized(which obviously is so since you say that it displays true if you uncomment the commented line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that is problem related to the extra spaces in the the string so try it.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String res = getServerData("http://10.0.2.2/auth.php?username="+username.getText()+"&password="+password.getText());
        //txt.setText(res);
        Log.d("MyActivity",res);
        if("true".equals(res.trim()))
            txt.setText("SUCESS");
        else
            txt.setText("FAILED");
    }
});
```

if this work or not.

please inform me i want to know exactly going on.

Comment: how do you check Log.d output?

Comment: Check the Log.d(..) output into Logcat window.